# Nested Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT id
FROM `events` 
WHERE heading LIKE '%somestr%'
AND guests_since_start > 10
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `submissions`
WHERE `submissions`.event_id = `events`.id)!=0;
```

Currently this query crashes my server. The idea is to get all id's from the events table that have corresponding rows in the submissions table (the events and submissions are linked by an event_it. As long as the number of rows is not 0, then I would like those records to be displayed.

The problem is the `events` table has approximately 3,000 records, while the `submissions` table has approximately 290,000.

Any help on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct join will filter it for you and be more efficient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM `events` 
    INNER JOIN `submissions` 
    ON `submissions`.event_id = `events`.id
WHERE heading LIKE '%somestr%'
AND guests_since_start > 10
```

DISTINCT is required to filter out duplicates. This reduces the efficiency a bit (since MySQL now now has to remove dups), but overall it'll be much faster than any subquery.  Indexes on `submissions.event_id` and `events.id` will help further.

Comment: A covering index on (events.id,events.guests_since_start) would almost certainly increase performance further. I believe JOIN is only slightly faster than EXISTS in this instance, but this is probably the fastest query.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd rewrite the query as:

```
   SELECT e.id
     FROM events e
    WHERE e.heading LIKE '%somestr%'
      AND e.guests_since_start > 10
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM submissions s WHERE s.event_id = e.id);
```

OR as Matt S pointed out (I believe his may be slightly faster, but I prefer the reduced syntax):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT e.id
     FROM events e
     JOIN submissions s
       ON s.event_id = e.id
    WHERE e.heading LIKE '%somestr%'
      AND e.guests_since_start > 10
```

You were doing an unnecessary count on submissions.

I'd also make sure I had indexes covering (e.id, e.guests_since_start) and (s.event_id).